# Using Function.prototype.bind with an array of arguments?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, promise, partial-application

How can I call Function.prototype.bind with an array of arguments, as opposed to hardcoded arguments? (Not using ECMA6, so no spread operator).

I'm trying to put a promises wrapper around a module that uses callbacks and I want to bind all of the arguments passed in to my wrapper method and bind them. Then I want to call the partially applied bound function with my own callback, which will resolve or reject a promise.

```
var find = function() {
  var deferred, bound;
  deferred = Q.defer();
  bound = db.find.bind(null, arguments);
  bound(function(err, docs) {
    if(err) {
      deferred.fail(err);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(docs);
    }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work because bind expects arguments rather than an array of arguments. I know I could do this by inserting my callback onto the end of the arguments array and using apply:

```
arguments[arguments.length] = function(err, docs) { ... }
db.find.apply(null, arguments);
```

Or by iterating over the arguments array and rebinding the function for each argument:

```
var bound, context;
for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
   context = bound ? bound : db.find;
   bound = context.bind(null, arguments[i]);
}
bound(function(err, docs) { ... })
```

But both of these methods feel dirty. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe your last example is wrong. You just keep overwriting `bound` in each iteration. So you end up with `bound` bind `db.find` with the last argument bound to it.

Comment: Wasn't concentrating when I jotted it down. Cheers for the heads up.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`.bind` is a normal function, so you can call `.apply` on it.
All you have to do is pass the original function as the first param and the desired `THIS` variable as the first item in the array of arguments:

```
bound = db.find.bind.apply(db.find, [null].concat(arguments));
//      ^-----^            ^-----^   THIS
```

Whether that can be considered cleaner or not is left to the reader.

Comment: Of course. Fantastic! Cleaner in concept, but in practice? I think not.

Comment: Yeah, personally I'd find it rather confusing. It would probably help to wrap this in a function, something like `function bindArray() { ... }`, which makes the intend clearer.

Comment: A small note: [null].concat(arguments) yields [null, arguments] because arguments isnt treated like an array. Instead, this worked for me:
var argsAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
bound = db.find.bind.apply(db.find, [null].concat(argsAsArray));

Comment: @Otts Arguments not being treated as an Array is also easily fixable, using Array.prototype.slice, since it accepts the arguments object and returns an Array. The whole function will then become `bound = db.find.bind.apply(db.find, [null].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));`

Comment: @MartijnOtto This is exactly what I wrote in my comment, isn't it? The only difference is that you inlined my definition of argsAsArray (which I wouldn't prefer for the sake of readability).

Comment: It might be worth noting that the first item in the arguments will need to be the `this` object for the bind function

Comment: Magnificent... callback.bind.apply(callback, [this, data]) -- Thx a ton!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Chaining _functionName.bind.apply(this, ['test', 'test2']) results in the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Bind must be called on a function. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Zeb: It doesn't seem `this` refers to a function in your case. If `_functionName` is a function, then you probably want `_functionName.bind.apply(_functionName, ['test', 'test2']) `.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. That must be it, i thought the first argument to apply was the context, not the function. Thank you !

Comment: @Zeb: In this case you are calling `bind.apply`, i.e. you are setting the context of `.bind`, and that must be a function. I now think you want `_functionName.bind.apply(_functionName, [this, 'test', 'test2'])`

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense actually. I realized that apply would take the array of args, and pass them to bind correctly, but overlooked the second context switch.

Comment: Javascript is causing serious damage to my brain sometimes :(

Comment: I know this is an old post, but using this resulted in 30% performance improvement of a function I was writing.

Comment: the first reference to `db.find` (or _functionName) is extraneous and (I would argue) confusing.  The proper implementation is `bound = Function.bind.apply(db.find, [null].concat(arguments))`

Comment: @codechimp: Yeah, I can see that. However, `Function.bind`, while maybe nice to read, is essentially the same as `db.find.bind` or `Array.bind`, or any other reference to `.bind` via a function object. `Function.prototype.bind` might be more correct.

Comment: This answer should be edited to add slice(), as it is wrong as it stands.

Comment: How about using: ```var arg=[this,...Array.from(arguments)]; bound = db.find.bind(...arg);``` ?

Comment: @Xerix: In that case I would just do `db.find.bind(this, ...Array.from(arguments))`.

Answer (score 11):

The following is a common snippet of code I use in all my projects:

```
var bind = Function.bind;
var call = Function.call;

var bindable = bind.bind(bind);
var callable = bindable(call);
```

The `bindable` function can now be used to pass an array to `bind` as follows:

```
var bound = bindable(db.find, db).apply(null, arguments);
```

In fact you can cache `bindable(db.find, db)` to speed up the binding as follows:

```
var findable = bindable(db.find, db);
var bound = findable.apply(null, arguments);
```

You can use the `findable` function with or without an array of arguments:

```
var bound = findable(1, 2, 3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Function.prototype.bind` and `Function.prototype.call`?

Comment: @torazaburo It wouldn't really matter because `Function` is itself a function. Hence, it inherits `bind` and `call` from `Function.prototype`. Therefore, I used the shorter of the two forms because... I am a lazy sadist who likes to confuse people with terse code.

Comment: Bindable is bind,bind,bind ? I feel a song coming on.

Answer (score 9):

Felix's answer didn't work for me because the `arguments` object isn't really an array (as Otts pointed out). The solution for me was to simply switch `bind` and `apply`:

```
bound = db.find.apply.bind(db.find, null, arguments);
```

Comment: I found this conceptually slightly more difficult (I wanted a bound function call, I have a bound apply call), but it makes sense (I call bound apply, function is called just as well) and is syntactically much clearer :).

Comment: I find it easier to understand if written as `Function.apply.bind(db.find, null, arguments)`. The general `apply` method is bound to execute `db.find` with context set to `null` and arguments array set to `arguments`.

Answer (score 4):

For those using ES6, Babel compiles:

```
db.find.bind(this, ...arguments)
```

to:

```
db.find.bind.apply(db.find, [this].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
```

I think it's fair to say Babel is pretty definitive. Credit to @lorenz-lo-sauer though, it's almost identical.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply bind to the arguments array as per your example, and have the `bound()` function treat it just like that, *as an array*?

By the looks of your usage, you are then passing in a function as the final argument to `bound()`, which means by passing in the actual argument array, you avoid having to separate arguments from callbacks inside `bound()`, potentially making it easier to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Generically, this schema suffices:

```
//obj = db
//fnName = 'find'
var args = [this||null].concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
obj[fnName].bind.apply(obj[fnName], args);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find following cleaner than the accepted answers

```
Function.bind.apply(db.find, [null].concat(arguments));
```

Comment: I did not know about Function.bind (but i used Function.prototype.bind). Is it part of any standard ?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for an abstract sample:

```
var binded = hello.apply.bind(hello,null,['hello','world']);

binded();

function hello(a,b){
  console.log(this); //null
  console.log(a); //hello
  console.log(b); //world
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had an alternative idea, partially apply the `null` value for context and then use `apply` to call the partially applied function.

```
bound = db.find.bind.bind(null).apply(null, arguments);
```

This removes the need for the slightly spooky looking `[null].concat()` in @Felix's answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `db.find.bind.bind(db.find, null).apply(null, arguments);`?

Comment: I guess fn.bind.bind.apply is just as spooky as the [null] concat :-)

Answer (score 0):

A definitive and simple answer might be

```
Function.apply.bind(this.method, this, arguments);
```

Kinda "hard" to grasp, yet, neat.

Comment: Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Just a side remark in case someone lands here after reading only the title of the question.
I know the OP didn't want to use ES6 spread operators **and** explicitly asked for a call to `bind()`, so my answer is apparently twice off-topic.

However, it appears the actual need was to apply `bind()` to an unbound function (i.e. not a method), which makes `bind` essentially unnecessary.

`bind()` has to handle special cases (like enforcing the value of `this` for a constructor) which costs some computation time that is wasted if you just want to apply some parameters to an ordinary function and don't care about `this` to begin with.

A naive version of `bind()` stripped of the sanity checks and OOP-specific fiddling with `this` could be:

```
Function.prototype.naive_bind = function (fixed_this, ...fixed_args) {
    const fun = this;
    return function(...free_args) {
        return fun.call(fixed_this, ...fixed_args, ...free_args);
    }
}
```

So you can write your own pseudo-bind that drops `this` and does a "partial application" of your actual parameters:

```
function partial_application (fun, ...applied_args) {
    return function(...free_args) {
        return fun.call(null, ...applied_args, ...free_args);
    }
}
```

If you want to apply all your arguments and leave room for a last one, you can drop the extra parameters too:

```
function total_application (fun, ...applied_args) {
    return function(free_arg) {
        return fun.call(null, ...applied_args, free_arg);
    }
}
```

If your arguments are inside an array, you can destructure them:

```
function total_application_from_array (fun, [...applied_args]) {
    return function(free_arg) {
        return fun.call(null, ...applied_args, free_arg);
    }
}
```

I suppose you could use apply instead of call, but you'd have to add the extra free parameter to the array.

```
function total_application_from_array (fun, applied_args) {
    return function(free_arg) {
        return fun.apply(null, [...applied_args, free_arg]);
    }
}
```

so you'd use that as:

```
var a = partial_application (console.log, 1, 2, 3);
a(4,5,6);             // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
a("hello", "world");  // 1, 2, 3, hello, world

a = total_application (console.log, 1, 2, 3);
a()                  // 1, 2, 3, undefined
a(4, 5, 6)           // 1, 2, 3, 4

a = total_application_from_array(console.log, [1,2,3]);
a(4,5,6)             // 1, 2, 3, 4
```