# How does Function.bind.bind(Function.call) uncurry?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, this, function-binding

We have this line in my code base:

```
var uncurryThis = Function.bind.bind(Function.call);
```

That I'm trying to work through. Presumably, it uncurries. How do I work this out?

I guess it's a version of `Function.bind` whose own `this` is bound to `Function.call`. Doesn't help me enough. And I haven't found any uses, so I'm not even sure if you call it standalone or need to call it "as a method", only, you know, bind it first.

Comment: Where did you see this? Is part of a well-known library or just some magical line of code you found laying around with no comments or context?

Comment: @p.s.w.g He took a job at Google.

Comment: @djechlin I happened to find this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/uncurrythis/4). It might be useful.

Comment: I think that the term "curry" or "uncurry" used in the context of JavaScript is inaccurate in general; in this case, I'm not sure what it's intended to mean.

Comment: +1 to @Pointy that the use of ["curry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is quite wrong here. The Base2 library does call this function ["`unbind`"](http://base2.googlecode.com/svn/version/1.0.2/doc/base2.html#/doc/!base2.JavaScript.Function2::unbind)

Comment: Have a look at https://dev.to/melkornemesis/how-to-curry-this--uncurry-this-4l9f - I wrote an article demystifying uncurrying this with Function.bind.bind(Function.call).

Comment: @MelkorNemesis thanks -- you should probably attribute this question, iirc it's a license requirement.

Comment: Here's a clue, that would have been helpful for me: `Function.call === f.call === Function.prototype.call`

Answer (score 18):

It passes the `call` function to the `bind` function, with the `bind` function itself being the value of `this`.  Thus you get in return a wrapper around the `bind` function that arranges for `this` to be the `call` function when you call it. *That*, in turn, is a function that lets you create a wrapper around the `call` function bound to some argument you pass it.

In case you haven't been drinking coffee nonstop since you woke up this morning, step by step:

- `Function.bind.bind` is a reference to the `bind` function. The reference is generated from a property of — confusion point 1 — the `bind` function itself. Remember, the `bind` function, when called with some function as the object, is used to create a wrapper around that function with `this` bound to the first argument passed in.
- Thus that function call gives you a function back. That function works as if you called `Function.call.bind(something)`.
- If you pass some random function as an argument to *that* function, then, you get back a wrapper around the random function that, when called, will act like `randomFunction.call(whatever)`.

So:

```
function random() {
  alert(this.foo);
}

var bb = Function.bind.bind(Function.call);

var randomcall = bb(random);

randomcall({ foo: "hello world" }); // alerts "hello world"
```

The ultimate point is this: you've got a function, and inside the function there's code that expects `this` to have some properties, and it uses `this` in one way or another. You'd really like to be able to use that function with some object here, some object there. You can obviously do that with

```
random.call(someObject);
```

But this magic "bind-bind-call" trick gives you a cheap way to create a variation on your function that lets you avoid the explicitly-coded invocation of `.call()`.  It also allows you to hang onto your senior front-end developer position for a little bit longer.

*edit* — I'm going to spoil the punch line above because I just thought of a good reason to use the bind+call trick to obtain a function that arranges to make a call to some desired function that expects to operate via `this` on some "owner" object. Let's say you've got an array of strings, and you'd like to get a version of those strings in lower-case. You could write this:

```
var uc = ["Hello", "World"];
var lc = uc.map(function(s) { return s.toLowerCase(); });
```

But with the magic "bb" function we could also write:

```
var uc = ["Hello", "World"];    
var tlc = bb(String.prototype.toLowerCase);
var lc = uc.map(tlc);
```

Not much of an improvement written that way, but if one were to make a set of `bb()`-ified wrappers of all the handy String prototype methods, it might make more sense. Of course, everything has a price, and it's probably the case that such wrappers will have some performance impact. (If practices like this were common then runtimes could probably be improved.)

Comment: I laughed my coffee through my nose for you. Is there some way to follow and get more programming humor from you?

Comment: @pilau ha ha thanks for finding this; I was looking for it the other day but couldn't find it :) I'm usually not that funny!

Comment: Do you have a blog or something? Surely someone with so many rep score must have a blog!

Comment: @pilau I do but I'm too lazy to write to it. There was something I was going to write about the other day though, so maybe I'll get the energy. I'm going to a conference next week so maybe I'll write some stuff then :) (Oh and the blog is linked from my profile.)

Comment: Have a great time at the conference! Meanwhile this might be on topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21792913/1049693

Answer (score 7):

OK. You know what [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does? It's a method of Functions to fix their `this` argument, and returns a new function. It could be simplified to:

```
function bind(context) {
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(context, arguments);
    };
}
```

I will abbreviate function calls with contexts in a more functional style with lots of partial application: bind<sub>fn</sub>(context) -> fn<sub>context</sub>. With arguments: (bind<sub>fn</sub>(context))(…) is equal to fn<sub>context</sub>(…).

Similarly, [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) does take a `this` value but instead of returning a function, it applies it right now: call<sub>fn</sub>(context, …) -> fn<sub>context</sub>(…).

So now let's get at your code: `bind.call(bind, call)`. Here, you're applying `bind` on `bind` with `call` as the this value: bind<sub>bind</sub>(call). Let's expand this (with above rule) to bind<sub>call</sub>. What if we now supplied some arguments to it?

> bind<sub>bind</sub>(call) *(fn)(context, …)*
>
> bind<sub>call</sub> *(fn)(context, …)*
>
> call *<sub>fn</sub>(context, …)*
>
> *fn<sub>context</sub>(…)*

Step by step, we could do

> uncurryThis = bind<sub>bind</sub>(call) `//` bind<sub>call</sub>
>
> func = uncurryThis(method) `//` call<sub>method</sub>
>
> result = func(context, …) `//` method<sub>context</sub>(…)

A practical use case for this are any "class" methods that are supposed to be converted to a static function, taking the object (on which the method would be called upon) as the first argument:

```
var uncurryThis = Function.bind.bind(Function.call);
var uc = uncurryThis(String.prototype.toUpperCase);
uc("hello") // in contrast to "hello".toUpperCase()
```

This can be helpful if you cannot place a method call, but need a static function; e.g. as in

```
["hello", "world"].map(uc) // imagine the necessary function expression
```

Also, the method you want to invoke might not be a method of the object itself, as in

```
var slice = uncurryThis(Array.prototype.slice);
slice(arguments) // instead of `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` everywhere
```

---

If it helps, here is also an explicit implementation, without any binds:

```
function uncurryThis(method) {
    return function(context/*, ...*/)
        return method.apply(context, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be explained more clearly if you work backward.

**Context:**

Suppose we want to lowercase an array of strings. This can be done like so:

```
[‘A’, ‘B’].map(s => s.toLowerCase())
```

Let's say, for whatever reason, I want to make this call more generic. I don't like how `s` is bound to `this` and the fat arrow is tied to `toLowerCase()`.

How about this?

```
[‘A’, ‘B’].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase)
```

Well, this doesn't work because `map` passes the element as the first argument but `String.prototype.toLowerCase` takes no arguments. It expects the input string to be passed as `this`.

So a question is can we create a `wrapper` function that makes this work?

```
[‘A’, ‘B’].map(wrapper(String.prototype.toLowerCase))
```

`wrapper` returns a function that turns the first argument passed into `this` for `String.prototype.toLowerCase` to use.

I claim that your `uncurryThis === wrapper`.

---

**Proof:**

So let's not try to understand `unCurryThis` all at once. Instead, let's use some formulas to transform `unCurryThis` into something more understandable.

Some formulas first:

```
instance.function(...args)
=== (instance.constructor.prototype).function.call(instance, ...args)
=== (Class.prototype).function.call(instance, ...args) [1]
=== (Class.prototype).function.bind(instance)(...args) [2]
```

For example,

```
Class === String
instance === 'STRING'
function === toLowerCase
args === []
---
'string'.toLowerCase()
=== ('STRING'.constructor.prototype).toLowerCase.call('STRING')
=== (String.prototype).toLowerCase.call('STRING')
=== (String.prototype).toLowerCase.bind('STRING')()
```

So let's just blindly apply these formulas without worrying about what the confusing `uncurryThis` looks like:

```
'string'
=== (wrapper)(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')
=== (uncurryThis)(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')
=== (Function.bind.bind(Function.call))(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')

// Function.bind is not really the generic form because it's not using the prototype
// Here Function is an instance of a Function and not the constructor.prototype
// It is similar to calling Array.bind or someFunction.bind
// a more correct version would be
// someFunction.constructor.prototype.bind === Function.prototype.bind, so
=== (Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.call))(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')

// Apply formula 2
// instance.function(...args) === (Class.prototype).function.bind(instance)(...args) [2]
// Class === Function
// function === bind
// instance === Function.prototype.call
// ...args === String.prototype.toLowerCase
=== instance.function(...args)('STRING')
=== (Function.prototype.call).bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')

// Apply formula 2 again
// Class == Function
// function == call
// instance === String.prototype.toLowerCase
// ...args === 'STRING'
=== instance.function(...args)
=== (String.prototype.toLowerCase).call('STRING')

// Apply formula 1
instance.function(...args) === (Class.prototype).function.call(instance, ...args) [1]
// Class === String
// function === toLowerCase
// instance === 'STRING'
// args === []
=== instance.function(...args)
=== 'STRING'.toLowerCase(...[])
=== 'STRING'.toLowerCase()

// So we have
(wrapper)(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')
=== (uncurryThis)(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')
=== 'STRING'.toLowerCase()
=== 'string'
```

---

**Reverse Proof:**

So you might wonder "how did the guy even derive the `uncurryThis` function"?

You can reverse the proof to derive it. I am just copying the equations from above but reversed:

```
'STRING'.toLowerCase()
=== (String.prototype.toLowerCase).call('STRING') // apply formula [1]
=== (Function.prototype.call).bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING') // apply formula [2]

// At this point, you might wonder why `uncurryThis !== (Function.prototype.call).bind)
// since it also takes (String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')
// This is because passing in (Function.prototype.call).bind) as an argument
// is the same as passing in Function.prototype.bind
// `this` binding isn't done unless you call
// (Function.prototype.call).bind)(String.prototype.toLowerCase)
// at that exact moment.
// If you want to be able to pass unCurryThis as a function, you need to bind the
// Function.prototype.call to the Function.prototype.bind.

=== (Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.call))(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING') // apply formula 2
=== (Function.bind.bind(Function.call))(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING') // un-generic-ize
=== (uncurryThis)(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')
=== (wrapper)(String.prototype.toLowerCase)('STRING')

=>

unCurryThis === wrapper === Function.bind.bind(Function.call)
```

Still pretty confusing to follow but try to write out what `Class`, `function`, `instance`, and `args` are each time I am applying formulas [1] and [2], and it should make sense.

Answer (score 0):

when we call bind on a function, it returns new function with this is replaced by context:

```
function random() {
  alert(this.foo);
}
var newRandom = random.bind({foo:"hello world"}) //return new function same as //`random` with `this` is replaced by object {foo:"hello world"}
```

the same we have:

```
Function.bind.bind(Function.call)
// return new Function.bind with its `this` is replaced by `Function.call`
```

It has following source(used simplified version of `bind` function given by @Bergi):

```
var bb = function bind(context){
  var fn = Function.call;
  return function() {
        return Function.call.apply(context, arguments); //also replace fn here for easier reading
    };
}
```

Notice that context here will be function, for example `random`, so wen call bb(random) we has `newRandom` function as:

```
newRandom = function(){
   return Function.call.apply(random, arguments); //also replace 
}
//`apply` function replace `this` of Function.call to `random`, and apply Function(now become `random`) with arguments in `arguments` array.
```