# Javascript: Passing a method that is callable with a "this" object

Tags: javascript

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar
  }

  getBar() {
    return this.bar
  }
}

function unmethodize(f) {
  return function(object, ...args) {
    return f.apply(object, args)
  }
}

const unmethodizedGetBar = unmethodize(Foo.prototype.getBar)

function test() {
  foos = [new Foo(1), new Foo(2), new Foo(3)]
  return foos.map(unmethodizedGetBar)
}
```

I know about `foos.map(foo => foo.getBar())` etc.

I simply want a version of `getBar` that takes the "this" object as its first parameter. Does it already exist somewhere, or must I create it via `unmethodize` or some such?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does that.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it already exist somewhere?

No, you'll have to create it yourself. The `getBar` in your class defines only a method that expects a `this` argument.

If you don't want to use an arrow function or write your own `unmethodize` function, you can however achieve this with builtins only:

- [`const unmethodize = Function.bind.bind(Function.call);`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23482982/1048572)
- `foos.map(Function.call.bind(Foo.prototype.getBar))`
- `foos.map(Function.call, Foo.prototype.getBar)`

But seriously just use the arrow function :-)