# Trying to understand effect of binding the call function

Tags: javascript, function, this

I came across following (cleaned up) code and trying to understand what exactly is going on. I'm generally aware that bind function accepts this paramete, first parameter acts as argument etc. Also read the documents on mdn about how call/apply methods behave. However I'm having hard time understanding following syntax

```
var eObject = Object,
    DeObject_bind = eObject.bind,
    neObject_call = eObject.call,
    object_call = neObject_call.bind(DeObject_bind, neObject_call),
    reObject_apply = eObject.apply,
    object_apply = object_call(reObject_apply)
```

What exactly is happening here? For example it seems like object_call is bound with this set to Object.bind. What does this achieve? Same for apply - what exactly is happening?

Comment: If you found this code without an accompanying thorough explanation, you may want to look for better sources.

Comment: @Pointy, some javascript code is intentionally obfuscated and employees the techniques discussed here. They are not going to put comments in the code, however as a developer, I want to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: Well it's not really obfuscated; those are perfectly readable function calls with fairly clear names for variables and functions. The issue is that it's creating shorthand bound functions that can do things that are academically interesting, but not really practically useful.

Comment: Starting with `eObject = Object` is weird. One would have expected `eObject = Function.prototype`

Comment: @Bergi the code is just looking for a shortcut to `Function.prototype.bind` and `Function.prototype.call`.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, but still why start at `Object`? They could at least have used `Function.call` and `Function.bind`

Comment: Probably related: [How does Function.bind.bind(Function.call) uncurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23482982/1048572) and [Chaining 'bind' and 'call' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31198503/1048572) - but `call.bind(bind, call)(apply)` is a step weirder

Comment: @Bergi who knows what sort of twisted logic drives the authors of stuff like this?

Comment: If it helps, the my cleaned up code snippets came from what seems to be browser fingerprinting library. I am curious about what kind of information is collected from these scripts. One example is at https://login.xfinity.com/login, comcast_common.js. I've seen such scripts on many websites. You can check the source directly

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to abbreviate those long variable names (the first two) as simply `bind` and `call`, because that's what they are.

Thus `neObject_call.bind(DeObject_bind, neObject_call)` is better written as

```
call.bind(bind, call)
```

meaning that we'll get a bound function that will be a shorthand for `bind.call(call)` with optional extra parameters. Why? Well, `call.bind(bind)` will bind the `bind` function itself as the `this` value in a call to the `call` function, as if we were doing `bind.call()`. Generally, to use call you take some random function `fn` and write `fn.call(someThis, someValue)`. So binding `call` to `bind` makes a shorthand function for `bind.call()`.

Thus `object_call(reObject_apply)` is basically

```
bind.call(call, apply)
```

That calls `bind` with `call` as the `this` value, so it's like

```
call.bind(apply)
```

which makes a bound version of `call` with `apply` as the `this` value. That, then is like

```
apply.call(...)
```

That lets you call `apply()` "naked" instead of `someFn.apply()`, instead allowing you to pass the function as the first parameter.

Why would anybody do this? Well, it might be useful to have versions of those meta-functions that can easily be used in things like `.map()` or `.reduce()`, I *guess*.

Comment: It's also useful if you want to use `.call()` and `.apply()` but don't trust the environment not to have messed up `Function.prototype`

Comment: Yea good point I guess